# Reactjs onChange doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a component where user can upload an image and display the image before its uploaded. The input field for the file is hidden, and instead a div is displayed where the user can click, and it will fire the click event on the input field, which will enable user to insert an image.

This is all working fine, but when the user insert an image, the `onChange()` is not fired. What am I doing wrong?

```
export default class CreateArticlePublish extends React.Component {
    insertImage = () => {
        article_image: this.refs.article_image.click();
    }
    displayImage = (event) => {
        imagePlaceholder: this.refs.imagePlaceholder;
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        imagePlaceholder.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div id="publish-metadata">
                    <form>
                        <label for="article_image">Image for the article</label>
                        <input type="file" name="pic" id="article_image" ref= "article_image" accept="image/*" />
                        <div id="image_placeholder" onClick={this.insertImage} onChange={this.displayImage} ref="imagePlaceholder">
                            <p>Click here to add an image</p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe onChange should be on <input /> ?

Comment: @Mary Yes. That was it. I didn't notice before. Thank you.

Comment: @mary should post an answer for this so that robin can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Attach onChange on the input instead of the underlying div